# make a call from twilio subaccount(makeCall)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I am using twilio voice-quickstart-ios. Currently i am trying to make call from subaccount using twilio REST API. Here is my makeCall endpoint

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  console.log("event :" + JSON.stringify(event));
  var to = event.to;
  var from = event.from;
  let subaccountSid = event.sid;
  let subaccountAuthToken = event.token;
  const accountSid = context.ACCOUNT_SID;
  const authToken = context.AUTH_TOKEN;

  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken, {
     accountSid: subaccountSid
  });

  client.calls
    .create({
        url: 'http://twimlets.com/message?Message%5B0%5D=Hello%20from%20your%20subaccount',
        to: to,
        from: from
    }, function(err, call) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err : " + err);
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
            console.log("call Sid " + call.sid);
            callback(null, call);
        }
  });
};
```

And bellow is the code to perform a voice call from my app.

```
func performVoiceCall(uuid: UUID, client: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
    guard let accessToken = fetchAccessToken() else {
        completionHandler(false)
        return
    }
    let dictionary = userdefaults.getSelectedNumbersSidAndAuth()
    let sid = dictionary["sid"]!
    let token = dictionary["token"]!
    let from = self.dialView.selectedNumberInDropdown

    let connectOptions: TVOConnectOptions = TVOConnectOptions(accessToken: accessToken) { (builder) in
        builder.params = [twimlParamTo : self.outgoingValue!, "sid" : sid, "from" : from, "token": token]
        builder.uuid = uuid
    }
    let call = TwilioVoice.connect(with: connectOptions, delegate: self)
    self.activeCall = call
    self.activeCalls[call.uuid.uuidString] = call
    self.callKitCompletionCallback = completionHandler
}
```

Now the problem is none of twilio's callback function get called. (eg: if callee or caller disconnects the call, delegates are not called). If i call from master account using [Twml](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial?code-sample=code-dial-a-phone-number-from-a-twilio-client-5&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) everything works fine. but i must have to call from sub account.
How can i be able to fix this? do i need to call makeCall endpoint from performVoiceCall function? If so how can i call this? please let me know.

Comment: If everything works from your master account, but not from a subaccount, then are you creating the access token using your master account details? You will need to use your subaccount details and create a TwiML App in your subaccount to use to make calls.

Comment: for every sub account do i need to create TwiML App? and using that AppSid i need to create accessToken, right?

Comment: Yes, you can create [TwiML applications via the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/applications), so you don't need to do it manually each time.

Comment: I am getting Authentication Failed. This is my [accessToken](https://pastebin.com/MaaA5Bwv) endpoint.
do i need to change any other information

Comment: after creating apiKey, apiSecret from sub account i am not getting Authentication failed but still delegates are not called when callee or caller disconnects or receives the call.@philnash

Comment: What delegate isn't getting called?

Comment: when callee or caller disconnects the call. for example, if caller disconnects the call it still calling on callees side and vice versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213064/discussion-between-philnash-and-a-rush).